# Can I use startsWith and endsWith in Java to check input?

Tags: java, loops, break

In Java can I use startsWith and endsWith to check a user input string? Specifically, to compare first and last Characters of the input?

EDIT1: Wow you guys are fast. Thank you for the responses.

EDIT2: So CharAt is way more efficient.

So How do I catch the First and last Letter?

char result1 = s.charAt(0);
char result2 = s.charAt(?);

EDIT3:  I am very close to making this loop work, but something is critically wrong.

I had some very good help earlier, Thank you all again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class module6
{
public static void main(String[]args){
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


   while(true){
   System.out.print("Please enter words ending in 999 \n");
   System.out.print("Word:");
   String answer;
   answer = scan.next();
   char aChar = answer.charAt(0);
   char bChar = answer.charAt(answer.length()-1);

   String MATCH = new String("The word "+answer+" has first and last characters that are the same");
   String FINISH = new String("Goodbye");


   if((aChar == bChar));
   {
   System.out.println(MATCH);
   }

   if(answer !="999")
   {
   System.out.println(FINISH);
   break;
   }
   }
   }
   }
```

The loop just executes everything, No matter what is input.  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I am making a Loop that takes user input and breaks out of the loop with a specific answer. But Any other answer that has matching first and last characters  like "Wow" or "Racecar" or "Noon" should reply with a different answer in the loop.

Comment: Lol, there are rewards for fast responses, makes sure we quick and accurate

Answer (score 3):

> In Java can I use startsWith and endsWith to check a user input string?

You certainly can: that is what these APIs are for. Read the input into a `String`, then use `startsWith`/`endsWith` as needed. Depending on the API that you use to collect your input you may need to do `null` checking. But the API itself is rather straightforward, and it does precisely what its name says.

> Specifically, to compare first and last Characters of the input?

Using `startsWith`/`endsWith` for a single character would be a major overkill. You can use `charAt` to get these characters as needed, and then use `==` for the comparison.

Comment: Alright that seems way better.  Now, I understand I would be using
"char result = s.charAt(0);"
but what about the character of the end of the word?

Comment: @epp5 That would be `s.charAt(s.length()-1)`. Of course you need to check length to be one or more to use `charAt(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you should be able to do that and it should be pretty striaghtforward. Is there a complexity that you are not asking?

Comment: Just remember to vlaid is inputStrign is not null. When any input is given.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact, not just characters, but entire strings too.

For example

```
public class SOQ4
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      String example = "Hello there my friend";

      if(example.startsWith("Hell"))
      {

         System.out.println("It can do full words");

      }

      if(example.startsWith("H"))
      {

         System.out.println("And it can also do letters");

      }

      if(example.endsWith("end"))
      {

         System.out.println("Don't forget the end!");

      }

      if(example.endsWith("d"))
      {

         System.out.print("Don't forget to upvote! ;)");

      }

   }

}
```

I recommend you use the API, here's a link to it http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html